# How to calculate relative average cost by department in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, inventory-management

So I am trying to calculate the average cost of On-Hand goods in this example.  The goal of this would be to determine the overall cost of goods by department.  This would be achieved arithmetically by taking the average cost of the good and multiplying it by the number of goods on hand for that item, and then repeating for each item.  I would then want to add items from the same numerical departments to get a department item cost.  Is there a way to do this within a single function in excel?  So far I have:

`=IF($B$2:$B$17=F2,SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$17,$D$2:$D$17),"null")`

but it is returning an invalid output.

For Cell J2, the output I would want to look for is: `$74093.80`

The reason I want to do this by function is because I have a spreadsheet with over 76,000 items and 19 different departments on it and need to calculate the Average Inventory Cost of each Department.

Thank you in advance!

[Click here for Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8HmA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the test inside the SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B$2:$B$17=F2),$C$2:$C$17,$D$2:$D$17)
```

Comment: @JConner please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.